# css td overflow

Tags: css, overflow

I have a table. I one of the td I have some longer text. When the text hits the right border, it goes to the line. Normal. What I would like is nevertheless a little different. When the first line hits the border I want the overflow to be hidden and have the last 3 visible characters be replaced by "...". Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers Marc.

Here the example:

```
http://cssdesk.com/3HTnq
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overflow does not work with tables.

You can place a div in the table to solve that.

[Here](http://cssdesk.com/xvpR2) a simple example based on your example

[text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow) is used to get the ... at the end.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I deleted the answer.

Comment: Hello Remy. You rock! It is too bad that it is not working with tables. Nevertheless I have a solution thanks to you. Great :) Cheers

Comment: @Remy - The vertical alignment is not working anymore. I can't manage to fix it. Can you help?

Comment: Take a look at the example I changed it according your input.

The td needs the height and vertical-align.

Answer (score 0):

#### Here's a little tweak.

```css
    td {
        max-width:1px;         /* makes all the difference! */
        white-space:nowrap;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Try it: https://codepen.io/dkellner/pen/MWObPgY

Apparently, if you use *max-width* and give it any numeric value, the browser suddenly understands that you're trying to cut the contents, but since it's not an explicit width, it will let the content grow. So it's kind of autosize plus crop, which was never possible as far as I remember. Again, not sure why literally *any max-width value* does the trick, `max-width:1px` should make it one single pixel wide; but it seems to work in all major browsers AND Microsoft Edge. (Sorry Redmond, couldn't help this one.)

You can even give it `text-overflow:ellipsis`, it just works as expected.